# Laravel, how to check file using hasFile if its in array?

Tags: php, laravel

If I'm using `$request->hasFile('attachment')` for the request as below, it works fine and returns true.

```
array:10 [ // app\Http\Controllers\Api\ComputerController.php:18
  "name" => "test_name"
  "attachment" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1965
    ...
  }
  ...
]
```

but if the `attachment` is in `receipt` array as below, `$request->hasFile('attachment')` returns false

```
array:10 [ // app\Http\Controllers\Api\ComputerController.php:18
  "name" => "test_name"
  "receipt" => array:2 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "supplier_date" => "2023-10-01"
      "attachment" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1965
        ...
      }
      ...
    ]
    1 => array:4 [
      "supplier_date" => "2023-09-01"
      "attachment" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1965
        ...
      }
      ...
    ]
  ]
  ...
]
```

I have tried using `$request->hasFile('receipt.attachment')` but it returns false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`receipt` has subarrays in itself which has attachments. To check if any of the subarrays has attachments, you can use the `*` notation to denote a level in the depths of nested arrays like below:

```
if($request->hasFile('receipt.*.attachment')){
  // your code
}
```